# How to get the Tag information for AES-CCM decryption using openssl

Tags: c++, openssl, aes

I am working on Security Application where it uses AES-CCM mode. Requirements of the application as shown in figure.

[image]

I was struck with decryption as my application is expected a TAG while decryption also.

According to the openssl [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption), We should provide the TAG along with TAG length as below.

```
/* Set expected tag value. */
if(1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_CCM_SET_TAG, 14, tag))
    handleErrors();
```

If I am not setting the Tag information, the result will be all zeros. I have gone through the implementation details of AES-CCM at [e_aes.c at line 3835](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/evp/e_aes.c), and found that if the expected tag is match with generated tag then only is result is updated. (Its my understanding)

**Could you please suggest me how to deal with this problem.**

**EDIT**
 I have create the image based on the requirement. Actually in the client code, they are storing the TAG value from encryption and comparing with the TAG generated while description. i.e, The comparison is happen at client code. So I need to revert the TAG which generated in Decryption to the client code.

Answer (score 1):

CCM (Counter with CBC-MAC) is defined in [RFC3610](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3610). The implementation of CCM with EVP described in [EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) is as follows:

- Encryption: During the [encryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption#Authenticated_Encryption_using_CCM_mode) the *tag is generated*:

  ```
   int ccm_encrypt(...){
       ...
       /* Set tag length */
       EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_CCM_SET_TAG, 14, NULL);
       ...
       /* Get the tag */
       EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_CCM_GET_TAG, 14, tag);   // tag is generated here
       ...
   }
  ```
- Then, the *tag is transferred* to the recipient together with the ciphertext.
- Decryption: During the [decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption#Authenticated_Decryption_using_CCM_mode) the received *tag is used* for authentication:

  ```
   int ccm_decrypt(...){
       ...
       /* Set expected tag value. */
       EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_CCM_SET_TAG, 14, tag);   // tag is provided here
       ...
       /* ...obtain the plaintext output...*/
       ret = EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len);   // tag is verified here
       ...
   }
  ```

Decryption only works if the tag used in the decryption is the same as the tag created during encryption. Otherwise `EVP_DecryptUpdate` returns 0 and provides an array of zero-values for the decrypted data.

I don't know where the image comes from, but IMO the decryption of AES-CCM using `EVP_aes_256_ccm()` is not described properly.

---

**EDIT:**

When using `EVP_aes_256_ccm()`, the encryption tag must be known for decryption (as described above) because decryption and authentication
are done in *one* step.

Of course, decryption and authentication can also be performed in *two* steps: In the first step, the decryption takes place using AES-CTR, i.e. plaintext and tag (CBC-MAC 1) are determined. In the second step, the tag (CBC-MAC 2) is calculated again from the plaintext using CBC-MAC (as it was done during the encryption process). Authentication is successful if both tags (CBC-MAC 1 and CBC-MAC 2) are identical.

To the best of my knowledge, however, there are no EVP-methods that *directly* support this approach. However, CCM is only a combination
of AES-CTR and CBC-MAC, which are combined according to [RFC3610](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3610). For this reason, you can also implement CCM in this way and use the
EVP_methods required for AES-CTR and CBC-MAC:

- For AES-256-CTR there is `EVP_aes_256_ctr()`.
- For the CBC-MAC AES-256-CBC is needed. For this there is `EVP_aes_256_cbc()`.
- Here are examples of [CBC-encryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#Encrypting_the_message) and [CBC-decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#Decrypting_the_Message) using EVP-methods. The corresponding EVP-methods for CTR result
  when `EVP_aes_256_cbc()` is replaced by `EVP_aes_256_ctr()`.
- The determination of the CBC-MAC is essentially a CBC-encryption, so that apart from `EVP_aes_256_cbc()` no other EVP-methods are needed here.

Since AES-CTR and AES-CBC are already implemented in the respective EVP-methods, most effort is required for the input formatting of both mechanisms. A good description can be found in [NIST Special Publication 800-38C](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-38c/final). It should be noted that today [AES-GCM](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-38d/final) has become the most popular AE(AD)-mode, see e.g. [this post](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/05/19/how-to-choose-authenticated-encryption/).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have create the image based on the requirement. Actually in the client code, they are storing the TAG value from encryption and comparing with the TAG generated while description. i.e, The comparison is happen at client code. So I need to revert the TAG which generated in Decryption to the client code. Don't know how to use openssl in this regards

Comment: It's getting clearer now. This description should have been included in the question. See the Edit-section in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Topaco. I will try to implemented this way.